# Having trouble with this switch inside my while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

So I am trying to replicate this game I've played before. In this game you are shown a number and there is a hidden number. You need to guess wether this hidden number is smaller, bigger, or the same as the number that is show. I am having issues getting the input to work. I can't seeem to get the switch statement to work. I am also having issues with the scanner. While it is on the outside of the while loop it works, but inside it doesn't.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Jamey {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            //This will give us the first random shown number
        Random yourRandom = new Random();
        int y = 1+yourRandom.nextInt(10);

        //Here is the introduction text
        System.out.println("Welcome to the guessing game!");
        System.out.println("The objective of this game is simple.");
        System.out.println("You will be shown one of two numbers which range between one and ten.");
        System.out.println("You have to gues if the number shown is larger, smaller, or equal to the hidden number.");
        System.out.println("If you believe the number you see is larger enter 1.");
        System.out.println("If you believe the number you see is smaller enter the 3.");
        System.out.println("If you believe the number you see is the same enter the 2.");
        System.out.println("Good luck, your number is "+y+".");

        boolean isDone = false;
        while(isDone=false){            

            //This allows the user to guess
            Scanner guess = new Scanner(System.in);
            int g = guess.nextInt();

            //This will help us to keep score later.
            int score = 0;

            //This will give us the new random number
            Random newRandom = new Random();
            int n = 1+newRandom.nextInt(10);

            //This will give us the new hidden number
            Random hiddenRandom = new Random();
            int r = 1+hiddenRandom.nextInt(10);

            //This is to allow multiple different inputs
            switch(score){
            case 1 :
                score +=1;
                if(y>r){
                    System.out.println("Correct");
                    System.out.println("Your new number is "+n+".");
                }
                else{
                    score +=1;
                    System.out.println("Inccorect, your overall score was "+score+".");
                    isDone = true;
                }
                break;

            case 2 :
                score +=1;
                if(y==r){
                    System.out.println("Correct");
                    System.out.println("Your new number is "+n+".");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Inccorect, your overall score was "+score+".");
                    isDone = true;
                }
                break;

            case 3 :
                score +=1;
                if(y<r){
                    System.out.println("Correct");
                    System.out.println("Your new number is "+n+".");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Inccorect, your overall score was "+score+".");
                    isDone = true;
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid input.");
                isDone = true;
                break;

            }       
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while statement is using assignment

```
while(isDone=false) // Incorrect
while (isDone == false) OR while(!isDone) // Better
```

Notice the `==` instead of just `=`. You weren't doing comparison, only setting `isDone` to false every iteration.

Your switch statement is failing because you are checking your `score` variable instead of the guess one.

```
switch(score) // Incorrect
switch(g) // Better
```

Also, you are creating lots of `Random` objects when you only need to create one single instance, then name each variable accordingly. For example

```
Random rand = new Random();
int yourRandom = 1 + rand.nextInt(10);
int newRandom = 1 + rand.nextInt(10);
int hiddenRandom = 1 + rand.nextInt(10);
```

Comment: while(!isDone) looks better

Comment: I've never seen when somebody write if (b == true), or something like this, everybody write if (b). Sometimes newbie doing this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I can't believe it was that simple.

Comment: Now all I am getting is getting the "Invalid Input" response from my default statement. Any help on that?

Comment: @user3203973 Updated my answer to include switch statement problem.

Answer (score 0):

`while(isDone=false){`
should be
`while(isDone==false){`
or even better
`while(!isDone){`

Comment: Thanks, the littlest things always get me.

Comment: Now all I am getting is getting the "Invalid Input" response from my default statement. Any help on that?